# Are "Where to buy X in city Y" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

This is in reference to [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/784/where-to-buy-cane-supports-in-london). IMO it is ok to ask *"what sort of **X** should I use to do **Y** to my plant **Z**"*, with the answers most likely containing suggestions to different products. But questions like *"where do I buy **X** in city **Y**"* certainly seems off-topic. Encouraging such questions will only lead to one such question for each city (and the worst part is, they are not technically duplicates!).

Any thoughts?

Comment: @Dori - I understand the ideas of the blog post (ask for best practice, not how to find specific product). But the crux of the post seems to be that given answers are obsolete very quickly, that will not be the case most of the time with gardening equipment. I don't disagree with closing the question, but its worth noting that this is not the fast paced tech environment of many other SE sites.

Comment: @wax eagle: True, but would you still want to clutter the place with such requests for each city?

Comment: not in the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I completely agree. Questions like that are only of worth to those in city Y and could change over time rendering the given answers useless.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I think in any other SE it would have been instantly closed as too localized (like asking on SciFi what "Milwaukee Book Store Sells E.E. Smith Novelettes").

And if one were to have asked "What International Chain Stores" sell X instead, I would have protested the question on moral grounds.

But, if someone just asked, "How do I get my hands on some of those X's?", then you have an indeterminate list of answers, also not suitable for this site.

So, yeah, since there is no appropriate way to answer the question, the question probably should be closed, not as 'off topic' but as 'too localized'.

Anyway, it's got answers.  As long as we don't close stuff like this before someone even has a chance to answer it, I'm OK with closing stuff.  It just won't be around for posterity.