# Terminology index

Tags: discussion

Is it possible and would it be useful to have a terminology index of common terms used on this site? Something like [Bicycles SE](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts) has but for gardening and landscaping? IMO, some index would be of great help to beginners and those who are not native English speakers ... like me :) ?

Comment: I apologize that this isn't really an answer to your question, but I tried to do something similar on a small scale, so I'll point you to it just for a look. I posted [What are the names of the parts of leaves?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/25235/what-are-the-names-of-the-parts-of-leaves?). It got an [awesome answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/25248/7305)! It was very helpful to me, but I have no idea how many people used it. It also got another answer which called it too generic and provided a Wikipedia link.

Answer (score 2):

I use Wikipedia, which has nice summary pages (leafs, hairs, flowers, habits, durability,...).

Because they are in Wikipedia, we could copy such figures and complete with some explanation. I could be nice to have such "one stop shop" will all terminology.

But I tried *Bicycles SE*, how I can find such page easy? If such index is not easy accessible, but just for few recurring people, I think it will not be so useful.

Or do you think this should be used as help in comment (e.g. on how to improve the question)?

Comment: Tbh, I'm not sure if there is option on SE to pin hot question to be easily accessible. Perhaps moderators can tell us if this is technically possible. Regarding Bicycles SE and their index, I can see this question in menu 'Questions' under 'Frequent' or 'Vote' (because it was rather popular question), they also have tags 'terminology' and 'glossary'. There is always an option of bookmarking this page in browser if user finds it useful. 
I also think that it would be better if users of G&L could post their answers instead of copying text from Wikipedia (generating more traffic on this site).

Comment: About Wikipedia: yes, I was thinking to copy the image and adapt them. Wikipedia allows this.

Answer (score 2):

I think we may want to use existing online comprehensive visual dictionary that is mentioned and linked to in my answer to a question on the main GL site:

[Resource for plant anatomy/lifecycle vocabulary](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7280/resource-for-plant-anatomy-lifecycle-vocabulary/36292#36292)

Or we can base ours on that dictionary. And rework it to something similar to the bicycle one.

Comment: If we were to try to do something like that, we'd have to do your second idea, which is to rework it, and bring the information here, with the link for a reference. SE should be where people go instead of Wkipedia! Also, some questions seeking off-site resources are likely to be called off-topic in the future. The meta post [Do we really want questions asking for off-site resources?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/634/) came to that conclusion. It was before your time, so you couldn't have been expected to know that, so I'm not criticizing!

Comment: In that answer you wrote, there's a link to a fascinating page about mushrooms. I use Firefox for a browser, and that page is telling me it uses a plug-in that might slow Firefox down. It wants me to activate a flash player, which I wouldn't do because I don't know enough about these things. Maybe it works fine on other browsers though!